# The function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Tags: themes, database, mysql, errors, sql

I don`t know coding. I recently my website stop to work properly. I get this error on the top of on every page loaded.

Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in /home/nortoniq/public_html/mywebsiteaddress.com/wp-content/themes/porto/functions.php on line 60

Anybody can help me with this error? much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_real_escape_string() instead mysqli_real_escape_string. For more information [CLICK HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ($link ,$source )  // $link is your connection variable
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I need to change this? is it in wordpress file or in SQL database or else? Sorry for lame questions ;)

Comment: in /home/nortoniq/public_html/mywebsiteaddress.com/wp-content/themes/porto/functions.php on line 60 replace this function